# Memory Leak/Crash converting image data

Tags: crash, xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, uiimage, nsdata

The following code crashes after ~200 calls. I've tried GC after each call and a MemoryWarning block with another GC, but it still crashes.

```
public byte[] ConvertImage(string base64String)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String ( base64String );
        base64String = "";
        NSData data = UIImage.LoadFromData ( NSData.FromArray ( encodedDataAsBytes ) ).AsPNG();
        encodedDataAsBytes = null;
        Byte[] returnBytes2 = new Byte[data.Length];
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy
        (data.Bytes, returnBytes2, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(data.Length));
        data.Dispose();
        return returnBytes2;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.LogError("ConvertImage", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

TIA,
Rick

After much head banging and superb help from Xamarin Support - the answer is to wrap the method in `using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool ())`

All is well now! Oh, and one other point, changing the .PNG to .JPEG reduced the load too.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty memory intensive. The base64 `string`, the `byte[]` array, the `NSData`, the `UIImage`, the second `NSData`, the second `byte[]` array. That's many times the required memory of the image you're working on.

Depending on how the code is called (e.g. a loop over a bunch of images) you might be allocating memory faster than the GC is able to reclaim it. At some point iOS will trigger a memory warning (but that won't help in a loop) and it will kill you if memory usage is not rapidly reduced.

You can easily lower your memory requirement by disposing of every `IDisposable` instance your code create. Right now you're disposing only one of the two `NSData` instances you create and you're not disposing of the `UIImage`. You could dispose of all of them like this:

```
byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String ( base64String );
using (var nsd1 = NSData.FromArray ( encodedDataAsBytes ))
using (var img = UIImage.LoadFromData ( nsd1 ))
using (NSData data = img.AsPNG ()) {
    byte[] returnBytes2 = new byte [data.Length];
    Marshal.Copy (data.Bytes, returnBytes2, 0, (int) data.Length);
    return returnBytes2;
}
```

Next, what's the purpose of the code later on ? i.e. what are you doing with the `byte[]` containing the PNG image ? It's not very useful by itself, but if you're only saving it to disk then you could do so from the `NSData` and skip the last `byte[]` allocation.

Other tricks, usage dependent, could also be applied (e.g. reusing the second `byte[]` buffer when possible) but we would need to know more about how the code is being used.

Comment: Still crashes. Actually gets through fewer records than my original code. The routine is called to convert base64 encoded image data from an XML file which is from a Desktop app.

Comment: You might want to transfer in binary instead of base64 string (to skip a step). OTOH you **better** measure before doing design changes (beside the obvious `Dispose` calls). Try using Apple's Instruments to see where and when the memory is being allocated and how you can avoid it (or reduce the time the memory is required). Once you have numbers (and more details about your app) then we'll be able to find/suggest more solutions (i.e. iterating on guesses is easy but generally not helpful).

Comment: Can't change the Desktop XML - it's out in the wild now. I can't get Instruments to work, in debug mode the thread running the Import never starts, not sure what's up with that. Why doesn't GC work in this situation????